# Implement transaction in java without using any library (like @Transactional)

Tags: java, transactions

I have a simple application which does below operation:-

1. withdraw from one account
2. deposit in another account

> ```
> private void transfer(fromAccount,toAccount, amount){
>     fromAccount.withdraw(amount);
>     toAccount.deposit(amount);
> }
> ```

Above implementation is quite risky without running in transaction context. How can I implement transaction without using any library or @Transactional.

Comment: With jdbc, JPA or hibernate, spring data?

Comment: Without using library.

Comment: Which database are you using?
Which driver are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: No database. keeping things in memory .

Answer (score 0):

```
private void transfer(fromAccount,toAccount, amount){ 
    boolean withdrawn = false;
    try {
        fromAccount.withdraw(amount);
        withdrawn = true;
        toAccount.deposit(amount); 
    } catch(Exception e) {
        if(withdrawn)
            fromAccount.deposit(amount);
        // you can throw another Exception here, otherwise you just fail silently
    }
}
```

This solution supposes that withdraw checks whether the requested amount is available or not and throws an Exception if not.

Comment: I am not talking about concurrency issues here. Well withdraw and deposit are thread safe . Issue here . if you don't have any framework support of transaction, how will maintain consistency. Suppose withdraw deducted amount but while deposit in another account some exception occur or there is connectivity issue, so it fail, in that case it will lead inconsistent state as money was withdrawn and not deposited in another account. This is the problem i am trying to solve without using inherent transaction framework support.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourClass() { 

   private void transfer(fromAccount,toAccount, amount) {
       Account fromAccountObj = new Account(fromAccount);
       Account toAccountObj = new Account(toAccount);
       synchronized(fromAccountObj) { 
          fromAccount.withdraw(amount);
       }
       synchronized(toAccountObj) { 
          toAccount.deposit(amount);
       }
   }
}

public class Account {
   private String accountNumber;
   public Account(String accountNumber) {
       this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
   }

   @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Account account = (Account) o;
        return accountNumber.equals(account.accountNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(accountNumber);
    }
}
```

Make sure your equals and hashcode returns same value for n number of objects of same account number

Comment: How it will rollback things if exception occur while deposit

Comment: That is a design call. 
1) Put that failed transaction in a separate in-memory queue and have separate logic to retry deposits for n number of times
2) Deposit back the money withdrawn from the fromAccount on exception.
3) Combination of 1 & 2

Once the transaction goes into a failed state, manual reconciliation needs to happen